# matplotlib, как выделить нужные точки на осях

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Как на графике отметить на осях конкретные точки , например, мне нужно отметь на оси y значения , которые функция принимает в точках z=1.5 и 2.3? И чтобы были линии параллельные осям, которые в нужных точках пересекаются. А ещё буду благодарен если подскажите как правильно масштабировать график , а то иногда  размер полотна увеличивается, а точки уменьшаются.

```
z = np.linspace(0, 5.9, 1000)
res = []
for i in z:
    res.append(v(i))

plt.grid(True, zorder=5)
plt.fill_between(z, res, zorder=10, color='k', alpha=0.5)
Plt.show()
```

PS: Цикл использую , т.к. в функции V использую функцию Хэвисайда

Comment: Вопрос в том как начертить ступенчатый график функции Хэвисайда?

Comment: Не, matplotlib автоматически  выбирает какие точки указать на оси Y и может пропустить нужные для меня,  я бы хотел выделить нужны мне точки на Y и соответствующие им точки на X + чтобы он линиями параллельными осям показал это соответствие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [21]: plt.grid(True, zorder=5)

In [22]: x_points = [1.5, 2.3]

In [23]: for i in x_points:
    ...:     plt.axvline(i)
    ...:     plt.axhline(np.heaviside(i, 0.5))
    ...:

In [24]: plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
Out[24]: (-0.1, 1.1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]